# How to use DCMTK in an iPhone project

Tags: iphone, dicom

I have already successfully used CCmake to compile dcmtk3.6 and build it in an ios environment, but I don't know how to include these compiled file in a new ios project.

I have already moved dcmtk after compiling to a new iphone project, and used `#include "dcm2xml.h"` but there is error about path.

Comment: You can have a look at how i compiled dcmtk for iOS here: http://www.brindusescu.org/article_32_lang_eng

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the iiDicom framework in QuickDicom.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickdicom/

iiDicom provides an ObjC wrapper for DCMTK, but it has not been updated for a while, so only handles DCMTK 3.5.4.  If you've already compiled DCMTK 3.6 for iOS, you should be able to cobble the two together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finished include dcmtk lib into IOS project. But with all option in Ccmake step are off. I will try your suggest later. Thanks.

Comment: @ĐôngHà Hi DongHa.... Can you please provide steps how to use dcmtk project. I am completely confused about how to use in iOS Project. Please edit your question with your success steps... or mail me at tariq2305@gmail.com Thanks