# How to compile DCMTK on iOS for the first time?

Tags: ios, ipad, dicom, dcmtk

I am going to work on DICOM images, so I need DCMTK to be compiled/installed in iOS.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to build DCMTK under Xcode 4.3, I'd suggest you start with the latest version from the DCMTK Git repository.  Start by building DCMTK for OS X on i386, using CMake to modify the various build options.  Once you have the OS X version built, use CMake to generate an Xcode project.  You'll find the the options you set for the i386 build will help you with the iOS project.

You will have to modify the CMake-generated Xcode project to build under iOS.  You should only modify the 19 DCMTK library targets.  Ignore the command-line tool targets completely.

There are instructions on how to create the DCMTK build for iOS.  Ignore them.  For the project file & the 19 library targets, do the following:

1 - Set the SDK option to "Latest iOS"

2 - You should no be able to modify the build architecture above the SDK option to "armv7"

Once you make these changes, you should be able to start building for iOS.

If you take Michael's suggestion to start with iiDicom, you'll need to modify those sources to work with UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

Try the iiDicom framework in QuickDicom.  See the long version of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484634/how-to-use-dcmtk-in-iphone-project/5654699#5654699)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 starting points for building the DCMTK library on iOS.  You can try looking here:

[DCMTK 3.6.0 on Github](https://github.com/ashtons/dcmtk-ios) 

[DCMTK 3.6.1_DEV](http://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3047&p=18140#p17872)

I created the 3.6.1 build.  If you can make use of it, go ahead.

I also have a cleaned up copy of iiDicom, should you need it.

My 3.6.1 build should work on iOS and macOS.