# Using DCMTK in iOS application

Tags: ios, ios5, dicom

I want to use DCMTK in my application and have successfully compiled DCMTK 3.6.0 for the iOS Simulator. Then I created a workspace into which I added the DCMTK project and my application. I added the .a files as target dependencies and linked the binaries. I think I am missing the part where I have to set the header/library search paths. I try to include a header file say #include "dcm2xml.h" and it says file not found. What am I doing wrong?

I have seen this. -> [How to use DCMTK in an iPhone project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484634/how-to-use-dcmtk-in-iphone-project?rq=1) But I think there's a simpler way without using that framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find some info on how to compile dctmk for ios and simulator [here](http://www.brindusescu.org/article_32_lang_eng),
and from [here](http://www.brindusescu.org/download/software/dicomViewer.zip) you can download a demo project which make use of the dcmtk. It will not display the image but will print the information found in some tags found in the file.  I hope it will help you start.